# How do I stub default void method of Mapstruct interface for Unit testing a class that is calling that default method?

Tags: junit, java-8, spring-test, mapstruct

I am unit testing a class in Java 8 that is calling a default method of a mapstruct interface and that method returns void. I am not able to stub the method call using Mockito.doNothing()...When(object).method(). The execution enters the actual method (in mapstruct interface) Pls provide your inputs to solve this problem.

Comment: what exactly are you doing inside the default method?

Comment: mapping based on boolean condition results

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?